# Match repeated digits from number

Tags: regex

I need regex to check numbers for repeated digits.

All numbers contain 12 digits, first 6 digits we need to skip, so I need to find numbers where every second digit from 7 repeated.

Like this `964632X5X7X3` X - repeated digits

Results

```
502632959793 - TRUE
125632757773 - TRUE
475632353773 - FALSE
```

I have try something like this for every digits from 0 to 9:

```
\d{6}([9]\d[9]\d[9]\d)$
```

It didnt work.

Comment: I'd use : `^\d{6}(\d)\d\1\d\1\d$`

Comment: \d{6}([9]\d[9]\d[9]\d)$
I have try something like this for every digits from 0 to 9 but it didnt work.
I am new one in regex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
^\d{6}(?=(\d))(?:\1\d){3}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/rJw1cT/1/). You may even refactor this regex later if you need to accommodate any x to y amount of repetitions after the first six digits (just replace `{3}` with the required `{x}`, `{x,}` or `{x,y}` quantifier with the required thresholds).

*Regex details*

- `^` - start of string
- `\d{6}` - the first six digits
- `(?=(\d))` - a positive lookahead that captures the seventh digit into Group 1
- `(?:\1\d){3}` - three occurrences of the digit captured in Group 1 and any single digit
- `$` - end of string